# Is there a way to prevent predictive text from learning what the user typed

Tags: ios, swift

I want to prevent predictive text from being stored on the iOS device. Is there a way to do it? If I turn off predictive text, the app doesn't show the predictive text toolbar, but it still learns the text. I know if the we implement a custom keyboard, predictive text does not get saved to the dictionary on device. I was wondering if there was another option than implementing a custom keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  The only remedy is to reset the Keyboard Dictionary (*Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Keyboard Dictionary*) and that too, is quite limited.  It’s an all-or-nothing scenario meaning if you accidentally added a misspelled word, you can’t remove just that one, all your custom words must go.

This is definitely something you want to submit feedback for:  https://apple.com/feedback/iphone

There is a potential solution, however, if you're willing to use a 3rd party keyboard - [Microsoft Swiftkeys](https://apps.apple.com/app/swiftkey-keyboard/id911813648).  I've been evaluating it for a while now and have found it quite capable.  Specific to your question, it has the ability to [delete individual auto-predicted words](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201674411-How-do-I-add-or-remove-a-word-with-SwiftKey-Keyboard-for-iOS-) instead of having to remove the entire dictionary. It's contingent upon signing into the swiftkeys account so that it can back-up and store your dictionary and settings.

[image]

Swiftkeys is free with in-app purchases which seem to only be the themes.  So, if you stick to just the included themes, you won't be out of pocket anything for this app.

Bear in mind that this is a third-party keyboard and will require "[Full Access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145696/what-does-the-option-to-allow-full-access-for-my-ios-keyboard-do)" for full functionality.  This means that *any* third party keyboard can see and send what you type back to the developers.  Google's keyboard, while strong on features, seems to be a [privacy nightmare](https://www.guidingtech.com/stop-gboard-collecting-personal-data).  While I don't trust Microsoft completely, I trust them much more than I do Google or other unknown app devs.

[Why does my Microsoft SwiftKey Keyboard need Full Access?](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201466641-Why-does-my-Microsoft-SwiftKey-Keyboard-need-Full-Access)

Comment: If that means *any* keyboard gets full access then why does both the question you link to and its answers imply that the Full Access option exists under *a particular* keyboard's settings?

Comment: Both questions  I linked to?  I linked  to  only  one  question. All others  were  were  off site  resources.

Comment: Both the question and its answers

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're getting at. I said *any* as in *each individual regardless of where it comes from*, so yes, the option will exist for each particular keyboard.  I'm not sure why that's an issue especially when it's tangential to the actual question.

Comment: I commented on this answer, because it's part of this answer. Whether or not that part of this answer is tangential to the question doesn't really concern me as a reader while I'm reading, as long as it's accurate and useful information. It's up to you whether you want to guard against the misunderstanding, of course.

Comment: The information is quite accurate, the issue here seems to be your interpretation of the word "any."

Comment: There's no issue with my interpretation of that word. It's most likely the same as yours. It's strange that you're trying to point out myself as the issue after I pointed out a sentence with potential for misunderstanding. You seem to think I'm the only one who could interpret the text another way. I don't think that, that's all.